# Why did On-premises Data Gateway sign-in fail?

Tags: azure, microsoft-powerbi

When attempting to setup Microsoft's On-premises Data Gateway, after successful installation, the login repeatedly returns a sign-in failure.

Following the setup process, an email address to setup the gateway is required.  I used an address that belonged to an Azure Global Admin/Domain Admin account.  However, once it tried to authenticate through ADFS, it failed returning a sign-in failure message.

All other logins from the same machine and account to O365 and Azure resources work fine.  Is there any reason/setting that would prohibit a sign-in?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by creating a "pure" O365 account and giving it a free PowerBI license. Once authenticated thru this new login, all other setup/configuration worked fine.

The workaround came from [this article](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/On-premises-data-gateway-sign-in-Receiving-quot-Non-HTTPS-url/td-p/86348), but it seems like it should work from a standard account.